# Angular background-color in global styles.css not working

Tags: angular

I added the following code to the global styles.css to have a lightblue background color.

```
html, body{
 background-color: lightblue ;
}
```

When I refresh the home.component page, I see lightblue screen briefly, then I get the home.component without the lightblue background.

What can cause the background color to be overriden by the home.component. I have no css file for home.component or app.component.

Update: I did, F12, element tab, filter on background. I see where the white color is overriding the style.css background color. It appears that the aws-amplify code is overriding my lightblue background color in styles.css

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's not enough context in your question, but you can try this `background-color: lightblue !important;` first. The color flashing could be attributed to your styles loading and getting applied first, and Angular's - second.

Comment: Most likely, you would have to provide a higher level of specificity for your CSS selector. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `!important` is a poor solution. 
You have most likely a css sheet overiding background-color property (check bootstrap if you are using it).
The best solution to fix it is opening console in your browser and check manually.

To do it :

- press f12
- click on top element
- filter by *background* property
- you will now be able to see which stylsheet is defining background color

You should see something like that.

[image: Screenshot of console in Chrome]

Comment: Paul, your way is outstanding. It appears the white background is coming from aws-amplify component. I will edit my post to add the pictures.

Comment: It appears the amplify-angular component is overriding the background color in angular.css file